# If two threads call the same function, but all the variables in the function are locals, do I still have to worry about sharing data between threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads

Say I have C++ code of the following high level format:

```
#include <thread>
void func1(vector<double> &somevec1, vector<double> &somevec2, size_t somesize){

  //somevec1 and somesize and a bunch of local variables being used to modify somevec2
  //somevec1 and somevec2 and somesize are all the same across all threads, but each thread is working on a different part of somevec2

}

vector<double> mainfunc(vector<double> &passingvector){

  //a bunch of stuff involving local variables

  // A thread is made that uses func1
  // Another thread is made that uses func1
  //in fact the number of threads being made that uses func1 depends entirely on the size of "passing vector"

  //a bunch of other stuff involving local variables

  //return the vector
}
```

Do I have to worry about all those threads sharing the data in the func1 function or would each thread have its own stack space for those func1 local variables?

If I do have to worry about that, then how can I get around fixing this problem? I'm extremely new to using threads. Would I have to use mutexes or semaphores to deal with this problem?

The reason why I ask this is because I keep getting a segfault, and I am trying to figure out whether or not it is because the threads might be sharing variables in func1. I'm trying to use gdb, but I'm fairly new to it so I have a hard time understanding what is going on. Does anyone know something that can help me identify a segfault in a more readable way?

Thanks :)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with the segfault. Your code doesn't reflect your question. If all variables are local you don't need to worry. But in your code snippet you use references which are not local variables. There you have to worry. I think the segfault is another problem.

Comment: You need to show more information - is each invocation of `func1` invoked on a different vector?

Comment: Hey Eric, I edited it. Hope it is more clear now

Comment: Updated my answer somewhat

Answer (score 2):

Each thread has its own stack and consequently its own independent local variables in the functions it calls.

However, those vectors you are passing by reference to the function could be shared (if you pass-by-reference the same vectors in different threads), and in that case synchronisation would be required.

Answer (score 0):

> would each thread have its own stack space for those `func1` local variables?

Yes, but that stack data includes:

- `addressof(somevec1)`
- `addressof(somevec2)`

That is, the pointers are copied, not the vectors themselves

If `func1` is called by two different threads with the same vector as an argument, then there is no guarantee it will be threadsafe:

```
vector<double> somevec1;
vector<double> somevec2;
size_t somesize;

// unsafe, these (might) modify the same vector!
auto t1 = std::async(std::launch::async, [&](){
    func1(somevec1, somevec2, somesize);
});
auto t2 = std::async(std::launch::async, [&](){
    func1(somevec1, somevec2, somesize);
});
```

```
vector<double> somevec1;
vector<double> somevec2;
vector<double> somevec3;
vector<double> somevec4;
size_t somesize;

// safe, these modify different vectors
auto t1 = std::async(std::launch::async, [&](){
    func1(somevec1, somevec2, somesize);
});
auto t2 = std::async(std::launch::async, [&](){
    func1(somevec3, somevec4, somesize);
});
```

You say in your question that

> `somevec1` and `somesize` and a bunch of local variables being used to modify `somevec2`

If `somevec1` is only being read from, you should declare it `std::vector<double> const&` or `std::span<double const>`, both of which will make the compiler error if you try to do anything non-thread-safe.

Modifying `somevec2` will be safe if:

- `somevec2.size()` is never changed (if this is true, declare the argument `std::span<double> somevec2` instead)
- No two threads access the same items in `somevec`. If possible, pass different `subspan`s of `somevec2` to enforce this.